# Is there a way to save a table in Spark local mode and retrieve if after a reconnection?

Tags: sparklyr

I'm using sparklyr with a local spark (2.3.0). I'm able to save a table with `spark_write_table` as in

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.0")
sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, "iris")
spark_write_table(tbl(sc, "iris"), "iris2")
```

The two tables "iris" and "iris2" are there:

```
 dbGetQuery(sc,"SHOW TABLES")
```

```
 database tableName isTemporary   
1 default     iris2       FALSE  
2              iris        TRUE
```

and the first one appears not to be temporary.

However if I disconnect from the session and reconnect using

```
spark_disconnect(sc)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.0")
```

I cannot find the "iris2" table anymore although the table is present in the spark warehouse directory.

Is this the expected behavior (Spark in local mode cannot store permanent tables) or is there a trick to be able to save and retrieve the tables when using the same warehouse directory?